# Example wikitude SDK

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, image-recognition, wikitude

I'm starting with the development of Augmented Reality and I have not found an example with step by step code explanation. Could someone help me with some basic example of image recognition in android SDK wikitude in using eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the SDK package you downloaded from http://www.wikitude.com/download it includes an sample application with many examples.

Image Recognition is used e.g. in the examples 1_ImageRecognition_ and 2_3dAndImageRecognition_

All examples are documented (/Documentation.html) and the example app can be found in /Examples/ with AR content living in /Examples/assets/samples